# How to better understand LVM and adding disks?

Tags: linux, lvm

I am playing around with understanding LVM and adding disks to a Linux box.  I added a disk and then ran what I thought were commands to add this disk to the box, but I think I messed up.

Did I just add this disk to the current LV and now I just need to resize it?  I tried to get this to mount but it comes back with the following error.

mount error..

```
mount -t xfs /dev/mapper/ol-lv_oradata  /mnt/drives/oradata
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/ol-lv_oradata,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

here are my outputs.

```
df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ol-root   27G   22G  5.1G  81% /
devtmpfs             1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                1.4G   32M  1.4G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                1.4G  9.6M  1.4G   1% /run
tmpfs                1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1            497M  282M  216M  57% /boot
tmpfs                276M   60K  276M   1% /run/user/54321


 ls -ls /dev/sd*
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  0 Jan  2 16:34 /dev/sda
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  1 Jan  2 16:34 /dev/sda1
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  2 Jan  3 13:53 /dev/sda2
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 16 Jan  3 13:50 /dev/sdb  <-- this is the disk I added
0 brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 17 Jan  3 13:53 /dev/sdb1 <-- this is the disk I added

fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0003e72b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048    62914559    30944256   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9a45daa3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   104857599    52427776   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/ol-root: 28.4 GB, 28420603904 bytes, 55508992 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ol-swap: 3221 MB, 3221225472 bytes, 6291456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ol-lv_oradata: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

 lvmdiskscan
  /dev/ram0          [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ol/root       [     <26.47 GiB] 
  /dev/ram1          [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/sda1          [     500.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ol/swap       [       3.00 GiB] 
  /dev/ram2          [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/sda2          [      29.51 GiB] LVM physical volume
  /dev/ol/lv_oradata [      50.00 GiB] 
  /dev/ram3          [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram4          [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram5          [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram6          [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram7          [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram8          [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram9          [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram10         [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram11         [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram12         [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram13         [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram14         [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/ram15         [      16.00 MiB] 
  /dev/sdb1          [     <50.00 GiB] LVM physical volume
```

here is the output of my lsblk..

```
sda                                                                                       
    |-sda1            xfs                              e86122cd-12b8-418a-af88-213c5f7cf198   /boot
    `-sda2            LVM2_member                      aTcqdV-CreW-yf1R-Et4Z-FXDg-a30f-bTa8ua 
      |-ol-root       xfs                              d3f701f6-bee6-4838-ad23-e004d6477e2a   /
      |-ol-swap       swap                             551085fa-4f56-474a-9fe4-926a50254506   [SWAP]
      `-ol-lv_oradata xfs                              40b962d1-ec00-44a1-8257-42d706c4839f   
    sdb                                                                                       
    `-sdb1            LVM2_member                      Q6IQCo-bR9J-XowP-gYzN-Nvfc-HcTG-UZDlL4 
      `-ol-lv_oradata xfs                              40b962d1-ec00-44a1-8257-42d706c4839f
```

Here is the output of `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs`

```
pvs
PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
/dev/sda2  ol lvm2 a--  <29.51g 36.00m
/dev/sdb1  ol lvm2 a--  <50.00g 0

vgs 
VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree 
ol   2   3   0 wz--n- 79.50g 36.00m

lvs
LV         VG Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data% Meta% Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
lv_oradata ol -wi-a----- 50.00g 
root       ol -wi-ao---- <26.47g 
swap       ol -wi-ao---- 3.00g
```

Comment: After running `lvcreate` did you run `mkfs` or similar?  If not then it's just an unformatted volume without a filesystem on it.

Comment: that might be it.  i saw that it showed under lsblk but nothing returns for blkid

Comment: Tried to run mksf.xfs -f /dev/sdb1 and it fails with cannot open /dev/sdb1: device or resource busy

Comment: Was able to run it using the lv path and it worked but still won't mount.

Comment: `mksf.xfs -f /dev/sdb1` - NO !!! you're trying to put a filesystem into the _same_ place as your VG. The LVM layer owns the disks (well, these partitions). Leave them alone.

Answer (score 2):

> Q : Did I just add this disk to the current LV and now I just need to resize it? I tried to get this to mount but it comes back with the following error.

A : If you want to extend you current LVM with new disk, first you need to create partition on new disk like @roaima already mention before then extend the current volume group of your LVM and then extend your LVM disk.

Reference :

[A Linux user's guide to Logical Volume Management](https://opensource.com/business/16/9/linux-users-guide-lvm)

[How to Extend/Reduce LVM’s (Logical Volume Management) in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

The output of `pvs` shows that you have two physical partitions assigned to your volume group `ol`. The output of `lvs` shows that you have three logical volumes in that volume group.

Your first `mount` attempt was accurate, so I suspect you hadn't formatted it.

```
mkfs -t xfs /dev/mapper/ol-lv_oradata
mount -t xfs /dev/mapper/ol-lv_oradata /mnt/drives/oradata
```

As an aside since you're learning about LVM, be aware that if you lose *either* of your disks you may well lose *everything* in the volume group that spans them. (Read up on the perils of "RAID 0" disk configurations for some detail. Your VG is configured in much the same way.)

Comment: Thanks to @roaima I was able to understand that I needed to do a little more reading.  I now understand physical and logical volumes along with volume groups.  like i said this is just a test server to teach me on how it works.